# How does sudo -E work here?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, environment-variables, repository, ppa

I executed the following command to add a ppa repository in Ubuntu:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa`

This command returned an error that the ppa name format is not correct. Then I looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/450643/185132) and thus, ran the follwing command:

`sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa`

The above command worked like magic. Then I read the man page for `sudo` which said that `sudo -E` preserves environment variables. What I do not understand is how preserving the environment variables helped me here?

Note: I am working behind a proxy.

Comment: Did you use a proxy?

Comment: @cuonglm: yes!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use proxy to make internet connection, maybe your system set some environment variable for your user to set the proxy server IP. When you use sudo without `-E` option, your environment variables are not preserved, so you can't connect to internet, causing `add-apt-repository` show that error. Checking `add-apt-repository` source code, you can see:

```
try:
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
except HTTPError:
    print _("Cannot add PPA: '%s'.") % line
    if user.startswith("~"):
        print _("Did you mean 'ppa:%s/%s' ?" %(user[1:], ppa_name))
        sys.exit(1) # Exit because the user cannot be correct
    # If the PPA does not exist, then try to find if the user/team 
    # exists. If it exists, list down the PPAs
    _maybe_suggest_ppa_name_based_on_user(user)
    sys.exit(1)
```

So if you can not connect to internet, `_maybe_suggest_ppa_name_based_on_user()` will be called. And here's its implementation:

```
def _maybe_suggest_ppa_name_based_on_user(user):
    try:
        from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad
        lp = Launchpad.login_anonymously(lp_application_name, "production")
        try:
            user_inst = lp.people[user]
            entity_name = "team" if user_inst.is_team else "user"
            if len(user_inst.ppas) > 0:
                print _("The %s named '%s' has no PPA named '%s'" 
                        %(entity_name, user, ppa_name))
                print _("Please choose from the following available PPAs:")
                for ppa in user_inst.ppas:
                    print _(" * '%s':  %s" %(ppa.name, ppa.displayname))
            else:
                print _("The %s named '%s' does not have any PPA"
                        %(entity_name, user))
        except KeyError:
            pass
    except ImportError:
        print _("Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.")
```

You can see, it will show the message `Please check that the PPA name or format is correct` if it can not import `Launchpad`. You need to install [python-launchpadlib](https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib) to make the import successful.

**Note**

I think it's ambiguous to report that message, since when the `launchpadlib` also need internet connection to work. In this case, the script should check weather the internet connection is down or not to report more clearly.